# What's the German quotation in The Sunset Limited?

Tags: dialogue, the-sunset-limited

In [The Sunset Limited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1510938/), White aka "the professor" (played by Tommy Lee Jones) quotes a short German sentence.

I am German myself, but I was unable to understand it. Were the words he said actually german? Did he just pronounce them in a strange way maybe?

What did he say and who did he quote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Analysing some subtitles I found out that the quotation can be:

> *Ich kann nicht anders*

Maybe the pronunciation wasn't that great. The quotation is attributed to Martin Luther:

> *Hier stehe ich, **ich kann nicht anders**. Gott helfe mir. Amen!: "Here I stand, **I cannot do differently**. God help me. Amen!"*

Comment: I just rewatched the scene, and you are right. The pronounciation is really bad though.

Answer (score -4):

1- literally: I cannot do otherwise. 2- meaning: I do what I want. 3- "I did it my way". 4- I am my own boss.